# Unable to properly stub a method with an argument instanciating a new Date

Tags: scala, mockito, stub

I'm working on a scala project and in my unit test I have to stub a method that takes as argument a Date(that is instanciated when calling the method), and I can't get to stub it porperly

However, I was able to find a turnaround using this post [How to mock new Date() in java using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887799/how-to-mock-new-date-in-java-using-mockito)
But I wonder if there is a better way to do this because I find that solution not very satisfying ...

here is the code I try to stub :

```
def foo(): Future[JsonObject] ={
 [...]
        for {
            a <- b.bar(arg,atDate = Some(Date.from(Instant.now())))
        } yield a
    }
```

I tried to stub it like that

```
val b = mock[B]
 when(b.bar(arg, _:Option[Date])).thenReturn(Future.successful(List()))
```

this doesn't parse,so I have to change it to :

```
val b = mock[B]
 when(b.bar(arg, _:Option[Date])).thenReturn({ d:Date => Future.successful(List())})
```

and when I run it I have the following error :

```
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Maybe I'm missing something in the error message but I don't find it helpful.
Is there any way to tell the stub to take whatever value for the date?
Also why does it require to put a function in thenReturn part, although the return type of the function is Future[List[A]]?

thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, the terrible `java.util.Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically, replaced by `java.time.Instant`. You can convert via new methods added to the old classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `any` matcher, so your code looks like (here I'm assuming `arg` is a variable defined somewhere else in your test code)

```
when(b.bar(ArgumentMatchers.eq(arg), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Future.successful(List()))
```

Now that's a bit verbose, so if you upgrade to mockito-scala and use the idiomatic syntax it would look like

```
b.bar(arg, *) returns Future.successful(List())
```

if you have/use cats, you can even do

```
b.bar(arg, *) returnsF List()
```

for more info check the docs [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)