# How to test @Scheduled annotated methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, time, scheduled-tasks

I was searching a long time for options to test @Scheduled annotated methods in Spring Boot Java application. There are several ways to trigger such a job (e.g. fixedRate, cron etc.).

Is there a general approach to test such methods?
In my project I need to schedule multiple processes (mostly using cron attribute of @Scheduled) and I need to have an overview about all of them.

My assumption was that some feature to inject custom `System.currentTimeMillis()` implementation that speeds up the time counter (let's say parametrized - 1x to 1000000x faster), so all depending Dates, Calendars and Timers will be immediately affected.

I have found nothing.

Comment: why exactly do you want to test it? it's a feature coming from the springboot-framework on a stable release, so it is working. i would rather suggest to test the method you want to invoke via scheduling and rely on the scheduling of it

Comment: You can test it by using a smaller time period delay (fixedRate or cron). Secondly, you can't manually inject a custom `System.currentTimeMillis()` implementation.

Comment: Maybe I didn t explain the problem clear... I don t need to test the method, but the varios executions of the method.
Let s say you have 3 different @Scheduled methods scheduled by different rules and I have no overview, what is the execution order of the methods. Especially if they are related somehow and could influence the target result (where the target result is the thing I need to check).
I would like to simulate a certain period of time letting the app be running - how the methods will be executed and what will be their output.

Comment: In addition to duplicate I linked, there's powermock way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415404/365237

Afaik, Spring doesn't offer any better, as [CronTrigger](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.java) has a direct dependency to java.util.Date.

Answer (score 1):

Never test framework features. Just test your methods. Injecting `System.currentTimeMillis()` needs some "hacking" and will be hard to maintain in the future.