# Java PowerMock: Mock NewDate whenNew, ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/tests/utils/ArrayMerger

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, powermock

I am getting 3 errors below when trying to mock New Date, using `PrepareForTest`.  How can I fix this?

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415404/15435022

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/tests/utils/ArrayMerger
> at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew(PowerMockito.java:506)

**Code below.**

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@PrepareForTest({ Product.class })
public class ProductTest {
    ....
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2022, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1);
    Date currentDate =  calendar.getTime();
    whenNew(Date.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(currentDate);
```

**POM:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: On which version of Java should that code be running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusions in Maven dependencies are used to prevent certain transitive dependencies from being included in the project.
It can help to prevent dependency conflicts, or classpath issues.

However, using wildcards to exclude all transitive dependencies, as shown in the original POM file:

```xml
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

is generally not recommended, as it can lead to unexpected issues such as missing classes and compatibility problems, and would explain the `NoClassDefFoundError` you are encountering (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/tests/utils/ArrayMerger`).

When using exclusions, it is best to be explicit and selective about which dependencies you are excluding, and to understand why you are excluding them. If you are not sure why an exclusion is needed, it is usually best to not include it, especially for testing libraries like PowerMock, which often have necessary transitive dependencies.

Consider also using the [latest version (2.0.9) of powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/releases) (2019), instead of 1.4.11 (pre-2017).

Finally, in your test class, you are using `@PrepareForTest({ Product.class })`. However, you are trying to mock the creation of a new `Date` object. You need to prepare the class that calls the `new Date()` constructor. This should be the class containing the code you are testing, not necessarily `Product.class`.

Your test class and POM file, with some of these suggestions, would look like:

**Test Class:**

```java
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ClassContainingNewDateCall.class }) // Replace with the class that calls new Date()
public class ProductTest {
    // ... rest of your code
}
```

**POM:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You will need to replace `ClassContainingNewDateCall.class` with the actual class that calls the `new Date()` constructor in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight: you're excluding *all* transitive dependencies, and then complaining that classes cannot be found at runtime?

`ArrayMerger` happens to come from `mockito-core`, which is bound to be one of the transitive dependencies you're excluding.