# Mocking class is returning null instead of data

Tags: java, testing, junit, null, mockito

In my Junit test, I'm doing the following in my Junit test :

```
   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        reportQueryParams = ReportQueryParams.builder()
            .id("07")
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void tabSerializerTest() {
        MetricsSerializer mockMonth = mock(MetricsSerializer.class);
            when(mockMonth.getCurrentMonth()).thenReturn("July");
        String tabSeparated = mockMonth.serializeMetrics(reportQueryParams);
        String expected = new StringBuilder().append("074")
            .append("\t")
            .append("July")
            .toString();
        assertEquals(expected, tabSeparated);

}
```

The function which I am testing:

```
public String serializeMetrics(final ReportQueryParams reportQueryParams) {
    stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("\t");
    addValueFromString(reportQueryParams.getId());
    addValueFromString(getCurrentMonth());
    return stringJoiner.toString();
}

public String getCurrentMonth() {
    DateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM");
    return monthFormat.format(new Date());
}


private void addValueFromString(final String value) {
    stringJoiner.add(value);
}
```

My ReportQueryParams class:

```
  public class ReportQueryParams {
        private String id;
    }
```

I am getting "null" in the actual data returned and hence the test is failing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mock the object you test.What you have written is "create a mock object that returns July for current month". But this mock object doesn't have real behaviour and the other methods return null.

When you test a class you mock the objects required by the class (in order to insulate behaviour) and not the actual class.  Here you can create a new MetricsSerializer (by using new :) and call it's method serializeMethod and compare against the current date (instead of July).

The way you have written the class might not be the best testable way though ;)

Comment: What i initially tried was : MetricsSerializer metricsSerializer = new MetricsSerializer();  and then I called .    String tabSeparated = metricsSeriazlier.serializeMetrics(reportQueryParams, remoteUser);  This returns the data, but I want to get something to compare against the current month. How can I compare against July?

Comment: You cannot compare against July because your method is made in a way that it uses the current date. If you compare against July it will fail and the correct behavior of the method is not to return July. Just create a new Date() in the test and compare the months

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are mocking the class, then testing the mock object, rather than testing a "real" object.  I can think of two possible solutions.

1. Use a Mockito Spy instead of a mock.  This is like a mock, but it's a real object, and the methods all have their normal behaviour, instead of "no behaviour" by default.  You can stub the `getCurrentMonth` method of your spy, to make it return what you want.
2. Since the real cause of your problem is the call to `new Date()`, you could use a time helper, instead of calling `new Date()` directly in your `getCurrentMonth()` method.  I have described this technique in detail in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11042200)