# how to mock timestamp and date function in java?

Tags: java, date, junit, timestamp, powermockito

how to mock following code? i dont want to change my code.

```
Date date = new Date();
String res_timestamp=new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString();
```

my code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    Date NOW = sdf.parse("2019-02-11 00:00:00");
    Timestamp time=new Timestamp(NOW.getTime());
    whenNew(Timestamp.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(time);
```

how can i mock it? am finding hard to mock it.

how can i solve it?

note: i do not want to change my code. without changing my code i have to mock those two lines.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use either `LocalDate` or `Instant` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for; I suggest you look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491260/mocking-time-in-java-8s-java-time-api ... the best thing to do in 2019 is to look into the `Clock` class. And yes, forget about Date and all that stuff. That is ancient past.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and testing convenience methods using Java 8 Date/Time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956373/writing-and-testing-convenience-methods-using-java-8-date-time-classes). Not an exact duplicate of what you asked, but could still give you and other readers what you all want.

Comment: guys, as mentioned earlier, i do not want to change my code. i would like to mock those two lines in my test cases rather than changing my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override Java System.currentTimeMillis for testing time sensitive code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis-for-testing-time-sensitive-code)

Comment: What above says. But I'm just going to reiterate again: I would rather you change your code.

Comment: In that case you HAVE TO refactor your code, and it's ok. I would recommend you to read more about unit testing and how it's connected with the code refactoring (for example, Roy Osherove's  "The art of unit testing")

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

- Use `java.time.Clock`, `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant`, `ZoneId`.
- Inject an altered `Clock` object as a dependency: `Clock.fixed( … )`.
- Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Timestamp`, `TimeZone`.

## Pass an altered [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) object as a dependency

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

The [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) class offers several alternate behaviors suitable for testing. These included a fixed point in time, altered cadences, and and adjustment from the current moment.

Pass one of these `Clock` objects to the various methods in the *java.time* classes for your testing purposes.

`PST` is not a time zone. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
```

Build up the specific moment you have in mind for your testing.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 2 , 11 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.MIN ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-02-11T00:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Calling `Clock.fixed` requires an `Instant`, a moment in UTC. We can adjust from our zoned value to UTC by extracting an `Instant`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-02-11T08:00:00Z

Specify a `Clock` that forever reports the current moment as that specific moment, without incrementing.

```
Clock clock = Clock.fixed( instant , z ) ;
```

> clock.toString(): FixedClock[2019-02-11T08:00:00Z,America/Los_Angeles]

Inject the fixed clock as a dependency.

```
Instant now = Instant.now( clock ) ;  // Tell me a lie.
```

> now.toString(): 2019-02-11T08:00:00Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ZzRQJN).

## JDBC 4.2

If you were instantiating `java.sql.Timestamp` for use with a database, instead use the *java.time* classes. As of [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), we can exchange *java.time* objects with a database.

Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) might have optional support for `Instant`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;            // Storing data.
Instant instant = myResultSet.get( … , Instant.class ) ;  // Retrieving data.
```

Your driver must support [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;            // Storing data.
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.get( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;  // Retrieving data.
```

[Adjust into a time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#atZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneId)).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).